# Docker Compose Access Container From Another Machine

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I deployed Spring Boot application using Jenkins by docker-compose.yml. I can access the created container, but I cannot access the container from another machine on the same network.

The command I used:

```
docker-compose run -d app
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  app:
    container_name: xxxxxx
    image: xxxxxx
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB_HOST="xxxxxxxxx"
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD="xxxxx"
      - POSTGRES_USER="postgres"
      - POSTGRES_DB="db_name"
```

How to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

After Jenkins deployed the application successfully, I used `docker inspect` to check the container's IP and then I accessed on the host machine(Let's say the container has IP 1.2.3.4) with the following URL:

```
http://1.2.3.4:8000
```

I try to access another machine in the network with the host machine by accessing URL like following(Let's say host machine has IP 2.3.4.5):

```
http://2.3.4.5:8000
```

But I could not see deployed web page like on the host machine, the error was like below:

```
This site can’t be reached
x.x.x.x refused to connect.
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to connect to?  What happens when you try it?

Comment: @David Maze I updated my post

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the use of the `docker-compose run` command. From [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/):

> The second difference is that the docker-compose run command does not create any of the ports specified in the service configuration. This prevents port collisions with already-open ports.

Because you're using `run`, the port mapping between the host port 8000 and the container port 8000 isn't configured.

The normal way you bring up a docker-compose stack is through the use of the `up` command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

You can specify a single service if you're trying to avoid bringing up all the services in your `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
docker-compose up -d app
```